# vue cli project missing build and web-pack config

Tags: webpack, vue-cli

I have install a `vue-cli` project and running the application. I need to put some rules in web-pack config.

It was supposed to be in build folder. But i don't see any build folder in my project root folder.

Do i need to manually add the build folder and write the web-pack config? Or, it can be install from some `npm` package?

I tried running `npm build` but it is just generating the dist folder. But not the build folder.

This is what i have installed:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
vue create ClientApp
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to fire following command for webpack initialization

```
vue init webpack my-project
```

Comment: This command is asking for the new project to create. Can't i install in the existing project?

Comment: https://github.com/prograhammer/vue-example-project/blob/master/README.md#add-dependencies this is very helpful to go through this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this command (vue init webpack my-project ) that is shared as the answer to your query above will only create a new webpack project of that template type. What you need is the build folder for your already existing project. 
You may want to try the below command to add your Vue- Build project:

npm install -g vue-build